# react native - Long press move

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to handle a press In react native app, so that :
When I touch the screen and move my finger across the screen,
I want to show the coordinates X and Y in real time, so by moving my finger the coordinates changes.

Comment: You can use pan responder or react-native-gesture-handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-gesture-handler](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler) and [react-native-gesture-detector](https://github.com/mxmzb/react-native-gesture-detector) to detect custom gestures which allow you to create gestures on the fly. Yep, just plug it in, paint the gesture and you will receive the coordinate data for your super-complex, custom gesture. You can use it to just use the data points as a predefined gesture in your app, or you can even let your app users create their own custom gestures